# Microsoft teams bot is incorrectly being identified as a Skype bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am unable to send messages to a teams bot developed using the Microsoft Botframework SDK using Python, When i investigated i found out while uploading the bots to team as a custom app, during the app validation phase, its treating the app as a skype app, Trace is in below screen shot, Which maybe the reason why the conversationid is not found as seen in the console errors in the screen shot . If anyone else has faced this issue or found a fix, please advise.

[image]

Comment: Could you please try using below sample and let us know if you are facing same issue? https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-conversation/python

Comment: Will try and let you the know the results

Comment: I tried the code sample, but still get the same error, like my Original code it works in Web Chat , but not in Teams

Comment: Let me know if this a bug? @Prasad-MSFT

Comment: We checked at our end and the sample works perfectly fine for us. Attaching the screenshot for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgc20.png

Comment: Can you share your manifest.json @Prasad-MSFT

Comment: Added the manifest json in 'Answer' section

Comment: it started working without making any changes on my end

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.14/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.14",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "137c09d3-76e2-40f2-a6f5-63a43bbb38c8",
  "packageName": "com.teams.sample.teamsconversationbot",
  "developer": {
    "name": "teamsConversationBot",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.teams.com/privacy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.teams.com/termsofuser"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "icon-outline.png",
    "color": "icon-color.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Python_Jega",
    "full": "Python_Jega"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "TeamsConversationBot",
    "full": "TeamsConversationBot"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "448ec85c-4395-4f80-b5a1-cd3bdefd1f5b",
      "scopes": [
        "personal",
        "groupchat",
        "team"
      ],
      "isNotificationOnly": false,
      "supportsCalling": false,
      "supportsVideo": false,
      "supportsFiles": false,
      "commandLists": [
        {
          "scopes": [
            "personal",
            "groupchat",
            "team"
          ],
          "commands": [
            {
              "title": "MentionMe",
              "description": "Sends message with @mention of the sender"
            },
            {
              "title": "Show Welcome",
              "description": "Shows the welcome card"
            },
            {
              "title": "MessageAllMembers",
              "description": "Send 1 to 1 message to all members of the current conversation"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [ "*.ngrok.io" ]
}
```